# Select tuple item from Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache Zeppelin to query data from Apache Cassandra.

I have tuples in my table as datatype.

```
frozen<tuple<float, float, float, float, float>>
```

How can I select one item from the tuple column? I want to select it directly in the sql statement.

```
SELECT x FROM table
```

will give me the whole tuple as result (x is the tuple column), but i just want e.g. the first or second item of the tuple.

Is there something like

```
SELECT x.1 FROM table or 
SELECT x[1] FROM table...
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the whole result with tuples, there was a change to allow using `x[1]` but it only covers collections like sets, maps, lists. You could change model to treat each element of the tuple as its own column instead of a single one.

Comment: Thank you, but I have about 50 columns, each a tuple of five values, I don't wanted to repeat the same structure (tuple) 50 times. Also it would need now to transform all existing data. I haven't used "sets, maps" in Cassandra, I will take a look on that...thx.

Comment: cqlsh:trader> select ts, aud_sgd[1] from candles2 where id=0 order by ts desc limit 10;
SyntaxException: line 1:18 no viable alternative at input '[' (select ts, [aud_sgd][...)

Comment: needs to be in a version after https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7396 which isn't available currently